# Pandas Multi-Colum Boolean Indexing/Selection with Dict Generator

Tags: python, pandas

Lets imagine you have a DataFrame df with a large number of columns, say 50, and df does not have any indexes (i.e. index_col=None). You would like to select a subset of the columns as defined by a required_columns_list, but would like to only return those rows meeting a mutiple criteria as defined by various boolean indexes. Is there a way to consicely generate the selection statement using a dict generator?

As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,50),index=None,columns=["Col" + ("%03d" % (i + 1)) for i in range(50)])

# df.columns = Index[u'Col001', u'Col002', ..., u'Col050']

required_columns_list = ['Col002', 'Col012', 'Col025', 'Col032', 'Col033']
```

now lets imagine that I define:

```
boolean_index_dict = {'Col001':"MyAccount", 'Col002':"Summary", 'Col005':"Total"}
```

I would like to select out using a dict generator to construct the multiple boolean indices:

```
df.loc[GENERATOR_USING_boolean_index_dict, required_columns_list].values
```

The above generator boolean method would be the equivalent of:

```
df.loc[(df['Col001']=="MyAccount") & (df['Col002']=="Summary") & (df['Col005']=="Total"), ['Col002', 'Col012', 'Col025', 'Col032', 'Col033']].values
```

Hopefully, you can see that this would be really useful 'template' in operating on large DataFrames and the boolean indexing can then be defined in the boolean_index_dict. I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know if this is possible in Pandas and how to construct the GENERATOR_USING_boolean_index_dict?
Many thanks and kind regards,
Bertie

p.s. If you would like to test this out, you will need to populate some of df columns with text. The definition of df using random numbers was simply given as a starter if required for testing...

Comment: Could you specify precisely what exactly is the expected output here given the input you described? Clear examples of input and output are very useful in case of abstract questions.

Comment: see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-query) for a new feature coming in 0.13 (coming very shortly). This allows you to essentially do this type of query directly.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, if I have understood things correctly, it looks like df.isin() may be the method to use that will take a dict containing the subset of columns and column_values? Also for Pawelmhm, Rutger Kassies has demonstrated how to complete this task using the df.apply method as the multi-boolean-index. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is your df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4,(100,50)),index=None,columns=["Col" + ("%03d" % (i + 1)) for i in range(50)])

# the first five cols and rows:
df.iloc[:5,:5]

   Col001  Col002  Col003  Col004  Col005
0       2       0       2       3       1
1       0       1       0       1       3
2       0       1       1       0       3
3       3       1       0       2       1
4       1       2       3       1       0
```

Compared to your example all columns are filled with ints of 0,1,2 or 3.

Lets define the criteria:

```
req = ['Col002', 'Col012', 'Col025', 'Col032', 'Col033']
filt = {'Col001': 2, 'Col002': 2, 'Col005': 2}
```

So we want some columns, where some others columns all contain the value 2.

You can then get the result with:

```
df.loc[df[filt.keys()].apply(lambda x: x.tolist() == filt.values(), axis=1), req]
```

In my case this is the result:

```
    Col002  Col012  Col025  Col032  Col033
43       2       2       1       3       3
98       2       1       1       1       2
```

Lets check the required columns for those rows:

```
df[filt.keys()].iloc[[43,98]]

    Col005  Col001  Col002
43       2       2       2
98       2       2       2
```

And some other (non-matching) rows:

```
df[filt.keys()].iloc[[44,99]]

    Col005  Col001  Col002
44       3       0       3
99       1       0       0
```

I'm starting to like Pandas more and more.

Comment: Hi Rutger, thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. I still dont understand how your generator works. All that I can undertand is that df[filt.keys()] returns a dataframe subset containing the columns used within the boolean index. The Pandas.apply method then applies a function to the rows, but why do we need x.tolist() in the anonymous function? Well done though as I would not have got there without your help.

Comment: You are correct about the first part, as for the second; since `filt.values()` returns a list, converting the row to a list in the lambda function allows it to be compared for equality directly, so the `x.tolist()` converts the row to a list instead of the default Series. 
It is worth noting that Pandas reorders the columns in the subset to as they are provided by 'filt.keys()', this guarantees that the order of the values in `x.tolist()` is the same as for `filt.values()`